# Component not added to JFrame

Tags: java, swing, jframe, jcomponent

I originally planned to have no dependance on java's window component system. However, I was forced to use it because it had double buffering. So this lead to my current problem. There are two JPanel components MainMenuDisplay and GameDisplay. Whenever you click the start button I want it to get rid of the mainMenuDisplay and replace it with a new gameDisplay. Whenever I attempt to do this, however, it removes the mainMenuDisplay and doesn't add the gameDisplay even though the code is obviously running. So it just leaves the JFrame without any components to run their paintComponent method. No errors are thrown. So why doesn't it add the new GameDisplay?
P.S. Please don't yell at me for using static objects.

```
Start.WINDOW.changeCurrentDisplay(new GameDisplay());
//Creates a new GameDisplay and passes it the JFrame
//This is inside MainMenuDisplay

//This is part of the JFrame class
Display mainMenuDisplay;
Display gameDisplay;
//Display class extends JPanel

public WindowManager() {
    super("Mountours - And - Men");

    setSize(settings.windowHeight, settings.windowWidth);
    setLocationRelativeTo(null);

    setResizable(settings.resizable);
    setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    setBackground(Color.WHITE);

    currentDisplay = new MainMenuDisplay();
    addKeyListener(currentDisplay.input);
    addMouseListener(currentDisplay.input);
    add(currentDisplay);


    setVisible(true);
}

public void changeCurrentDisplay(Display display) {
    removeAll();//Removes the MainMenuDisplay
    mainMenuDisplay = display;
    add(display);//Attempts to add component to JFrame, but doesn't, no errors either
    addKeyListener(display.input);
    addMouseListener(display.input);
}
```

Comment: When you call add method the components hierarchy is invalidated. If the container has been already displayed (as it is in this case) you need to call revalidate method. OTOH Google for CardLayout. It does exactly what you need to do.

Answer (score 0):

Instead you can use Visibility concepts to Achieve solution to your problem.
Just add two panels one above the other and 
Set Visibility true for one and false for other...
change Visibilities  according to usuage

in start button onclick event listener ..write the following code..it works like a charm

```
GameDisplay.setVisible(true);
MainMenuDisplay.setVisible(false);
```